# System calls vs C/C++ system calls

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

I'm currently writing a C program and one of the constraints is that I cannot invoke external programs using `system`. Instead, I need to work within the idiom of the language using system calls from within the C/C++ library. I'm having some troubles understanding the difference between "system" calls and "C/C++ system" calls.

Is `system` simply platform dependent while "C system" calls builds ontop of `system` and automatically changes its execution based on the platform being used?

Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give an example of an external program that you want to invoke?

Comment: Do you mean `fread` and `fopen` or rather `open` and `read`?

Comment: Yes, `system` just spawn a shell command to start any binary (or shell builtin) that you ask for. A system call is a call to a "feature" of the kernel, feature that kernel is the only one able to perform (i.e. "really" accessing hardware). Of course a program spawned by `system` can/will use system calls. I guess here that the goal is to force you to do it all, not relying on an existing binary that will do it for you.

Comment: @cad `open` was the one I had in mind but it was more of a general question.

Comment: Plausibly related, but not exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137628/alternative-to-system/28137786

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux-based operating systems expose functionality in two ways:

- command-line tools through a shell
- system calls through the C language

For example, to create a directory:

Using the shell, the `mkdir` command is used, see http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir.
The `system` C function invokes a shell to call such a command:

```
system("mkdir foo");
```

The corresponding system call is also called `mkdir`, now see http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir instead.

It is used directly in C like this:

```
mkdir("foo", 0755);
```

The benefit of using the latter call is that it is easier to check for error conditions, and that no forking takes place to delegate the work to a subprocess, which makes this solution faster and lighter in memory usage, among other things.

Answer (score 6):

The term "system call" is for the operating systems native functions, like `pipe` or `fork` or `write` (on POSIX platforms like Linux), it has nothing to do with the function `system`. Then you have the standard library which is specified in the C (or C++) specifications, and usually builds upon the operating systems native "system calls".

Read e.g. [this Wikipedia "system call" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), or [this about standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_library) for more information.

Also, no operating system call, or C (or C++) standard library function actuall calls the [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function, in fact the `system` function is implemented using lower-level *system calls* (like [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) on Linux). The [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) function is part of the standard library in C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

The [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function itself basically spawns a shell process and launches that program as if the user had just typed it from the command line himself.

"System calls" in the other sense are what the runtime libraries do to invoke the operating system to do something a program code couldn't do on it's own to. For example: opening a file, starting another process, and any type of I/O operations. On Linux, most of these system calls are exposed as C function APIs that your program can invoke do these operations (e.g. open, read, etc...).  All the Linux system calls are listed on the manual page here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Comment: I think this clarifies a lot for me. In otherwords, if I perform a system call such as open/read through the C library, it would still be considered 'within the language' correct?

Comment: Yes, but check with the person who gave you this assignment.